# How to get a named Doctrine Entity Manager to repository?

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I'm currently using Doctrine2 into Laravel via https://laraveldoctrine.org package and I run into problem with multiple connections.

I need to use multiple Doctrine Entity Mangers (EM) for multiple connections to get multiple databases working. To get default EM documentation suggests to use fe. Laravels container `app('em');`. But for named EM docs (https://laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.3/orm/multiple-connections) suggests to inject `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` into repository and than use method `getManager()` to get desired EM.

But - `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` is interface, I have no idea how to initialitze it and with what. So far I got:

```
class RandomRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $entityManager = $managerRegistry->getManager('namedManager');
        parent::__construct($entityManager, $entityManager->getClassMetadata(Random::class));
    }
}
```

but its wrong, because I got only ObjectManager and not the desired EntityManager.

Suggestion was to use factories like in ZF3 (factory definition for DI: https://pastebin.com/XuvB4fU6 & in each factory define it like this: https://pastebin.com/q5J60d3n), but it must be cleaner way how to use multiple EM without Symfony, is it?

Comment: What you have should work.  Is your IDE complaining?  Just typehint $entityManager against EntityManagerInterface to make it stop complaining.  Or use getManagerForClass($entityClass);

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - typehint helps, but I still need determine from what I can implement that ManagerRegistry interface?

Comment: Don't know "from what I can implement the ManagerRegistry interface' means.  I don't use laravel myself but from the docs you posted it seems like they already have an implementation.  If not then I suppose you could look at the symfony doctrine-bridge component for ideas.  But I'd be very surprised if the implementation was not already available and configured out of the box.

Comment: That is my point - in Symfony there is autowiring that handle the implementation. In Laravel has it too, but it probably does not work correctly in this package

Comment: The real problem is: 
How can one choose a different EntityManager than "default" in the ServiceProvider where app('em') seems to be the one and only possibility?